# query is taking long time to execute around 120 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, performance

1. my query is taking long time to execute around 120 seconds.
2. any one can help me to rewrite this query.
3. Please find Explain plan and table structure from below.
4. we are getting this query frequently in slow log.

#### Query:

```
   select count(*) as col_0_0_  
   from tab4 tab3, 
        tab5 tab1, 
        tab6 tt2aghierar_ 
   where tab3.own_domain_id = 263 
     and tab3.id=tab1.resource_id  
     and tab1.hierarchy_id = 18 
     and tab2.id=tab1.pattern_id;
```

#### Explain Plan:

```
   +----+-------------+--------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
   | id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys                                            | key                 | key_len | ref                              | rows   | Extra       |
   +----+-------------+--------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
   |  1 | SIMPLE      | tab1 | ref    | hierarcyHierarchyId,domain_id_hierarchy_id_resource_type | hierarcyHierarchyId | 4       | const                            | 111456 |             |
   |  1 | SIMPLE      | tab2 | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                  | PRIMARY             | 4       | comp1.tab1.pattern_id  |      1 | Using index |
   |  1 | SIMPLE      | tab3   | ref    | id,own_domain_id                                         | id                  | 4       | comp1.tab1.resource_id |      1 | Using where |
   +----+-------------+--------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
   3 rows in set (1.62 sec)
```

#### Table Structure:

```
   mysql> show create table tab4\G
   *************************** 1. row ***************************
          Table: tab4
   Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tab4` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `keyword_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     `keyword_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `description` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
     `own_domain_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `rank_check` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `rank1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `rank2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `rank3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `yesterday_entrances` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `week_entrances` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `current_ctr` float(16,4) DEFAULT NULL,
     `monthly_search_volume` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `avg_monthly_search_volume` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `traffic_increase` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `rank_improvement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `rank_update_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
     `top_rank_targeturl_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `frequency` int(10) DEFAULT '1',
     `score` float DEFAULT NULL,
     `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
     `bing_rank1` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `bing_rank2` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `yesterday_bing_entrances` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     `bing_rank_improvement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
     KEY `id` (`id`),
     KEY `keyword_name` (`keyword_name`),
     KEY `own_domain_id` (`own_domain_id`,`rank_check`),
     KEY `rank_check` (`rank_check`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=720988063 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
   /*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (`rank_check`)
   (PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (0) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION pEOW VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
   1 row in set (0.03 sec)
   
   mysql> show create table tab5\G
   *************************** 1. row ***************************
          Table: tab5
   Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tab5` (
     `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `domain_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `hierarchy_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `resource_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `resource_type` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `pattern_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
     `top_hierarchy_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `domain_id_resource_id_resource_type_top_hierarchy_id` (`domain_id`,`resource_id`,`resource_type`,`top_hierarchy_id`),
     KEY `hierarcyHierarchyId` (`hierarchy_id`),
     KEY `domain_id_hierarchy_id_resource_type` (`resource_id`,`hierarchy_id`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=126564587 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)
   
   mysql> show create table tab6\G
   *************************** 1. row ***************************
          Table: tab6
   Create Table: CREATE TABLE `tab6` (
     `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `pattern` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `hierarchy_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `match_level` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
     `flg` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `is_regular_expression` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
     `is_case_sensitive` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `hierarchy_id` (`hierarchy_id`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2293 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: It would help if you explain what the query is supposed to do.  Otherwise we have to decipher what you are doing, then rewrite it.

Comment: The query is retrieving the data from ttaghierar1_,ttaghierar2_,tkeyword0_ tables.

Comment: did you try indexing `pattern_id` on `t_tag_hierarchy_rel`, unless index already exists?

Comment: @pvr, yes I see that.  But what is the meaning of the query?  What are you actually trying to count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try this query instead of doing full joins:

```
select count(*) as col_0_0_  
from tab4 tab3
inner join tab5 tab1
    on tab3.id = tab1.resource_id
inner join tab6 tab2
    on tab2.id = tab1.pattern_id
where 
    tab3.own_domain_id = 263 
    and tab1.hierarchy_id = 18
```

Also you might want indexes on following columns:

```
tab4.own_domain_id
tab5.hierarchy_id
tab5.resource_id
tab5.pattern_id
```

Comment: hi @serigo this query is taking more time than my query if possible please provide  another solution